# Heroku CLI not working after update to macOS Monterey 12.2

Tags: heroku-cli, macos-monterey

I updated my macOS from Catalina to Monterey 12.2 a few days ago, and am no longer able to access Heroku from the command line (using zsh). Normally, running `heroku login` from the terminal will open Heroku in a web browser, and after logging in, I am able to run subsequent Heroku commands from the CLI.

Here's the input and error message I get:

```
% heroku login
fatal error: runtime: bsdthread_register error

runtime stack:
runtime.throw(0x2d5619, 0x21)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:566 +0x95 fp=0x7ff7bfeff6d0 sp=0x7ff7bfeff6b0
runtime.goenvs()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/os_darwin.go:88 +0xa0 fp=0x7ff7bfeff700 sp=0x7ff7bfeff6d0
runtime.schedinit()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:450 +0x9c fp=0x7ff7bfeff740 sp=0x7ff7bfeff700
runtime.rt0_go(0x7ff7bfeff778, 0x2, 0x7ff7bfeff778, 0x0, 0x1000, 0x2, 0x7ff7bfeff948, 0x7ff7bfeff978, 0x0, 0x7ff7bfeff97e, ...)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:145 +0x14f fp=0x7ff7bfeff748 sp=0x7ff7bfeff740
```

On first search of this error online, it seemed like maybe I needed to update Go, so I downloaded the latest version, and added it to my path like so:

```
% mkdir $HOME/go
% cd $HOME/go
% mkdir bin pkg src
```

and added the following lines to my .zshrc file:

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

(I then ran `source .zshrc` from the home directory).
This appeared to successfully update Go, because `go version` returns `go1.17.6 darwin/amd64`.

I ran `heroku login` again and got the exact same error. The same error occurs for any heroku command. Any clues on what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved the issue, though I'm still unclear on why that particular error message was showing up. Here's what I did:

I thought I might find answers in Heroku error logs on my computer. I couldn't use the `heroku logs` command, but I could search manually. Heroku's website says that these are located here `~/Library/Caches/heroku/error.log` on macOS. But this directory didn't exist. There was no `heroku` folder in `~/Library/Caches/`. I still had Heroku - `which heroku` correctly returned the path `/usr/local/bin/heroku`.

At this point I wondered whether the `CleanMyMac X` software I had used to clear storage space before updating my OS might have deleted the Heroku folder along with old error logs, and this might have prevented the program from opening?

**Solution**: I uninstalled the Heroku CLI based on instructions from Heroku's website:

```
% brew uninstall heroku
% rm -rf ~/.local/share/heroku ~/Library/Caches/heroku
```

and then re-installed with `brew tap heroku/brew && brew install heroku`

The installation failed, and homebrew prompted me to update some of the Command Line Tools:

```
% softwareupdate --all --install --force
% sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
% sudo xcode-select --install
```

After these updates, I tried again, and the heroku install succeeded. I have since been able to use Heroku commands using the CLI without problems.

Comment: That was really helpful -- thanks!

Comment: Worked for me without the xcode bit, but I was already up to date, cheers

Answer (score 3):

For me heroku CLI was pointing to the wrong place, so simply running `brew link --overwrite heroku` solved it. I'd follow the [recommendation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#homebrew-specific-issues) written by Heroku about Brew issues

Answer (score 1):

Following the [troubleshooting tips](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli#homebrew-specific-issues) on the Heroku website I checked which binary `heroku` was pointing to, and it turned out to be an old installation outside of Homebrew:

```
$ which heroku
/usr/local/heroku/bin/heroku # should be: /usr/local/bin/heroku
```

I deleted this installation, and then restarted the Terminal for `heroku` installed via Homebrew to be used:

```
$ rm -rf /usr/local/heroku
```